# SQL query not deleting data

Tags: php, sql

SQL is not deleting all the data in the query

SQL TABLE

```
BD int,
un  varchar(255),
branch varchar(255),
dates varchar(255),
morning_in varchar(5) default '{$time[0]->end}',
morning_out varchar(5) default '{$time[0]->end}',
afternoon_in varchar(5) default '{$time[1]->end}',
afternoon_out varchar(5) default '{$time[1]->end}'
```

```
BD  un     branch  dates       morning_in  morning_out  afternoon_in afternoon_out
```


104 Jason  HQ      2015-12-05  06:55       12:00        16:05        18:00
14  jack   HQ      2015-12-05  07:00       12:00        16:08        18:00
14  jack   HQ      2015-12-05  07:00       12:00        16:08        18:00

I need it to delete between `05:00` to `07:10`

```
$mssqldb->get_results("DELETE from tempUSERlog
        where morning_in BETWEEN '05:00' AND '07:10' AND
         afternoon_in BETWEEN '15:30' AND '16:10'");
```

I need it to delete between `07:00` to `12:10`

```
$mssqldb->get_results("DELETE from tempUSERlog
where morning_in = '07:00' AND 
morning_out ='12:00' AND afternoon_in='16:00'
and afternoon_out='18:00'");
```

Im using this piece of [class link](https://github.com/janjuna/mssql-db/blob/master/example.php)

PDO have issues on my Windows server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does PHP's Mssql even allow the Object Oriented Approach? I'm not seeing it here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php . I've not used it myself.

Comment: I'm thinking you should use PDO if you want to stay Object Oriented.

Comment: Please post sample data and show the layout of the table.  Also, what do you mean "not deleting all the data"?  What data is being deleted?  What do you want deleted that is not?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use 'or' operator instead of 'and' operator.

Comment: OR wont work because i'm trying to delete certain data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
DELETE from tempUSERlog
WHERE morning_in >= '07:00'
AND morning_out <= '12:00'
AND afternoon_in >= '16:00'
AND afternoon_out <= '18:00'
```

Probably you need to include your `dates` in your `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

You should use exec function in deleting data like the example in the link below. 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp

The function get_results should be used to get data not to delete data

Heres a link for sample crud 
http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/